# BodyContentImpl jsp tag memory leak problem

Tags: tomcat, caching, memory-leaks, heap-memory, jsp-tags

I am using Tomcat version 5.0.28, i was analyzing the heap dump. It shows the memory leak is due to the BodyContentImpl objects, which seems (not sure) it caches the content of the jsp between the tags.
Also i found there is a problem in that version,It doesn't resets the buffer it uses internally to hold data. There is option to limit buffer in the later versions of tomcat.

What i want to know is, What BodyContentImpl actually do, Is that caches the tags or data.
how it will be useful in a dynamically changing jsp.

Comment: Tomcat 5.0 is very old... can you upgrade?

Comment: You didn't understand my question,Simple what does the buffer do there

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your JSP tag stuff is cached. Specifically "JSP Custom Tag Pooling - The java objects instantiated for JSP Custom Tags can now be pooled and reused. This significantly boosts the performance of JSP pages which use custom tags."

To disable add to catalina.properties (or catalina_opts)

org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.USE_POOL=false
org.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true

to turn this off (However, I am not sure if this was ever backported to 5.0.x from 5.5.x)

See for example [Tomcat 5.5 Configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jasper-howto.html)